# Angular TypeScript innerHTML binding for input components

Tags: mongodb, angular, typescript, innerhtml

let's say I retrieve a [string] of HTML codes from MongoDB such as

```
["<div class=list-group-item><span><label>Enter text</label> : <input type =text placeholder=value [(ngModel)]=text0 index=gen > </span> </div>",
"<div class=list-group-item><span><label>Enter text</label> : <input type =text placeholder=value [(ngModel)]=text1 index=gen > </span> </div>"]
```

and I process I sanitize it and want to make it into a form with full functionality!

my html code:

```
<p>
  DATA:
{{this.id}}
</p>
<span *ngFor="let item of this.code;let x= index;"><div  [innerHTML]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.code[x])" ></div>
  {{this.item}}<br>
  WORK GOdDAMMIT!!: {{text0}}

</span>
```

I hard coded text0 to see if it decides to work!

Right now, Could you guys give me a basic example on how I could access the ngModel value so I can do it?

In AngularJS(v1.6) I managed to do it with an external module called bind-html-compile

Any small examples or such would be very beneficial!

If you want to have a look at my component.ts, here:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-form-show',
  templateUrl: './form-show.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form-show.component.css'],
   providers: [FormShowService]
 })
export class FormShowComponent implements OnInit {
  private id:string;
  private code:string;
  //private htmlCode :HTML
  constructor(
    private http: Http,
    private router: Router,
    private route : ActivatedRoute,
    private sanitizer: DomSanitizer
  ) {

  }

  ngOnInit(){
      //console.log(this.Code)
      console.log(this.route.params['value'].id);
      this.id=this.route.params['value'].id
      this.getID();
  }

getID(){
  let jsonData : JSON;
  jsonData=JSON.parse('{"data" :"'+ this.id +'"}');

  return this.http.post('/api/getInfo', jsonData).subscribe(
     res => {res.json();
       console.log(res.json());
       let resProc = res.json();
       console.log(resProc);
       this.code=resProc[0].script;
       console.log(this.code);
      });

}



}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have a much simpler solution for you and any of you who might run into a similar situation.I tried Viewcontainerreff but, to no avail.. After searching through npm.js, I believe that all you need is this package!

[The Fantabulous ng-dynamic](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-dynamic)

and it's usage is also pretty simple:

```
<div *dynamicComponent="your_html_string">loadin</div>
```

It works with angular4 directives and is all you need for such purposes!

Good Luck

~Ronny McNamara